# closurebuilder.py error on Windows: "can't decode byte 0x8f"

Tags: python, windows, utf-8, google-closure-compiler

I'm attempting to run closurebuilder.py on Windows, and no matter what files I pass, I get the same error from Python:

> python goog\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py --root=goog/closure/goog/ --root=closurebuilder-example/ --namespace="myproject.start"

```
goog\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py: Scanning paths...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "goog\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py", line 262, in <module>
    main()
  File "goog\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py", line 200, in main
    sources.add(_PathSource(js_path))
  File "goog\closure\bin\build\closurebuilder.py", line 175, in __init__
    super(_PathSource, self).__init__(source.GetFileContents(path))
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Code\Plain\goog\closure\bin\build\source.py", line 119, in GetFileContents
    return fileobj.read()
  File "C:\System\Python\33\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 6857: character maps to <undefined>
```

This error complaining about a UnicodeDecodeError with byte 0x8f occurs whether I'm trying to build a simple script, a blank file, or something more complex. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to create these files, and I've tried saving with both its default encoding (Windows Code Page 1252) and UTF-8.

To keep things dead simple I'm attempting to build the basic example in: https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder

In case that page changes here's the HTML and script I'm using:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script src="start.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      myproject.start();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
goog.provide('myproject.start');

goog.require('goog.dom');

myproject.start = function() {
  var newDiv = goog.dom.createDom('h1', {'style': 'background-color:#EEE'},
    'Hello world!');
  goog.dom.appendChild(document.body, newDiv);
};

// Ensures the symbol will be visible after compiler renaming.
goog.exportSymbol('myproject.start', myproject.start);
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: It is not processing a blank file if it finds an error in position 6857.

Comment: Do you know which version of Python is required? The difference between 2.x and 3.x is especially relevant.

Comment: @JanneKarila Updated to clarify exactly what I'm building when I get this error (the sample code from the closurebuilder.py docs). I'm using Python 3.3.2 for this. Neither the docs nor .py script specify what version to use, but the docs were last updated Feb 2013 so I'd guess 3.x is the major version they're looking for.

Comment: Try Python 2.7 if they don't mention Python 3 in their docs. Python 3 decodes text files automatically to Unicode using system's default encoding.

Comment: @JanneKarila That did it. Mind posting that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: "The Windows-1252 code points 0x81, 0x8D, 0x8F, 0x90, 0x9D are unassigned. They do not yet represent any characters" - http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/bug-double-conversion.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs do not seem to mention which version of Python is required. Python 3.x decodes text files automatically to Unicode using system's default encoding, which may be causing the error you are seeing on Python 3.3.

Try Python 2.7.

Comment: This was the issue - Closure Compiler requires Python 2.x, and will not work with 3.x. This is still not documented in Google's Closure Compiler documentation - they just link to the Python site, where one would reasonably assume the latest version is the right version (3.x).

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Python 2.7 was part of the solution for me, as suggested by @janne-karila However, after making that change I started getting the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

The solution of which was to add java.exe to the PATH.